# Convert dictionary of nested dictionaries into list of tuples

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I have a Dictionary of nested dictionaries:

```
d= {"name": {"weight": 150, "age":20},...."name":{"weight":170, "age":32}}
```

I want to convert this to a list of tuples, so I can easily sort on both weight and age....

```
new_d =[(name,150,20),(name,170,32)]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Comment: You *"can easily sort on both weight and age"* **without** that conversion. In fact that's probably what you **should** do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a list comprehension:

```
new_d = [(k, v['weight'], v['age']) for k, v in d.items()]
```